Uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^2 x^2} \sin(nx)$

Determine wether or not the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^2 x^2} \sin(nx)$ converges uniformly in $\Bbb R$.

This series is easily seen to converge pointwise, by considering separatly the case $x=0$ and $x\neq 0$, where the latter yields a series comparable to the convergent geometric series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (e^{-x^2})^n$. The "problem" with uniform convergence is that a naïve approach with Weierstrass' $\mathrm{M}$-test results with no immediate geometric series to use around $0$.
I tend to think the sequence $f_n(x)=e^{n^2 x^2} \sin(nx)$ is uniformly equicontinuous in $\Bbb R$. This would be sufficient to deduce the existence of a positive sequence $(M_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty M_n < \infty$ and $\forall x\in \Bbb R~~|f_n (x)|\leq M_n$, but I am not able to prove it.
